# SharePoint 2007 - How to configure different RootFolders for lists added to a page as web parts

Tags: list, application-pages

For example:

I have a page (http://examplesite/Pages/MyTeamPage.aspx) with two lists added as web parts.

**1.Invoices**

**2.Tasks**

I want to show different folders of each list.

Invoices - /Lists/**Invoice/2012**

Tasks - /Lists/**Tasks/RedTeam**

When I specify the RootFolder as a querystring I observe following behaviour

```
http://examplesite/Pages/MyTeamPage.aspx?RootFolder=/Lists/Invoices/2012
```

1.It shows only the content in folder 2012 in Invoices list

2.It shows all content in all folders in Tasks list including folders

```
http://examplesite/Pages/MyTeamPage.aspx?RootFolder=/Lists/Tasks/RedTeam
```

1.It shows only the content in folder RedTeam in Tasks list
2.It shows all content in all folders in Invoices list including folders

What I want to do is to have the MyTeamPage.aspx to show;

1.Only the content in folder 2012 in Invoices list

2.Only the content in folder RedTeam in Tasks list

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question in TechNet forum and got a reply from Parvez Akkas.  Thanks Parvez.

[SharePoint 2007 - How to configure different RootFolders for lists added to a page as web parts](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgenerallegacy/thread/77ffb808-9d79-4459-a7bf-17999d1a0bf5)

The answer is, what I want to do is not possible.  RootFolder value is valid for only one list.

**Edit:**

The reason I wanted to use RootFolder was, when I create a new item, it gets created inside the specified folder.  Without it the item gets created in root.

The reason to use folders in the list was that we need to configure security to groups of items.

The workaround I found for this is as follows.

1.Create folders for groups of items and configure security

2.Create meta data columns

3.In list view settings -> Folders -> select "Show all items without folders" option

4.Use FilterField1 FilterValue1 querystrings to filter results on the page

5.Create a feature to handle ItemAdding and ItemAdded events for the list

6.When creating a new item, copy the item that was created in root to a specified folder (folder name is extracted from query string) and delete the original item